# get just Last-Modified from php header

Tags: php, header

i try to get just  Last-Modified time  from php header but is not working, when i try to get all header it works

```
 $headers=get_headers("http://example.com");
 print_r($headers);
```

so i want to print just

```
print("Last-Modified: ".$headers[Last-Modified]."\n");
```

when i add this last line i get:  Last-Modified: HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
so is there a way to get just that or if that is  not possible then to print just that via preg_match or  strpos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) to parse the results:

```
$headers=get_headers("http://example.com", 1);
print("Last-Modified: " . $headers["Last-Modified"] . "\n");
```

Comment: if i want to compare 2 times and show diference
$1=$url1["Last-Modified"];
$2=$url2["Last-Modified"];

will this work: 
$mins = ($1 - $2) / 60;
echo $mins;